# Getting value from hash table return null

Tags: java, hashtable, actionlistener

I saved a String value in hash table,
but when I try to get it i always get null
can someone see why?

this is the code of the action listener:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()==btnSave){
            int day = Integer.parseInt((String)daysBox.getSelectedItem());
            int month = Integer.parseInt((String)monthsBox.getSelectedItem());
            int year = Integer.parseInt((String)yearsBox.getSelectedItem());
            MyDate date = new MyDate(day, month, year);
            System.out.println(date);
            diary.put(date,textArea.getText());
            textArea.setText(null);
        }
        if (e.getSource()==btnShow){
            int day = Integer.parseInt((String)daysBox.getSelectedItem());
            int month = Integer.parseInt((String)monthsBox.getSelectedItem());
            int year = Integer.parseInt((String)yearsBox.getSelectedItem());
            MyDate date = new MyDate(day, month, year);
            String s = diary.get(date);
            textArea.setText(s+" ");
        }
```

Comment: @Boann gives you the best answer. When such problem arises, the best way to find out what's happening is to set a breakpoint on `String s = diary.get(date);` and step into the function. You would probably have seen why it did not find your MyDate object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you have not overridden the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of your `MyDate` class. Hash tables rely on those methods to determine when two objects are considered equal. If you have not overridden them, the hash table will compare the MyDate objects to see if they are the same instances, which they will never be in your code because they are `new` instances created each time you do a get/put call.

In your MyDate class you will need something like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof MyDate)) return false;
    MyDate d = (MyDate)o;
    return this.day == d.day && this.month == d.month && this.year == d.year;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return ((day * 31) + month) * 31 + year; // 31=prime number
}
```